# DocuSign API sign using another account

Tags: docusignapi

I am wanting to use the DocuSign REST API to create an envelope for our clients. We are wanting to just create the envelope for our clients to simplify the DocuSign process. Each of our clients will have their own DocuSign account that would be separate from our API Integrator Key Account. I've looked into SOBO and Act-As-User in DocuSign however from what I can tell the user has to be a member of the same account as the API Integrator Account. Would anyone know if you can use another accounts details to create an envelope and how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to build a partner integration.

SOBO and Act-As-User is for same account authentication.

You would need the user to authenticate with their DocuSign credentials (or someone on the account can use SOBO), combined with your integrator key.

Comment: Yes, we are wanting to build a partner integration, so that they would login in with their credentials using our integrator key. the demo account only allows for one user and I am trying to test this to know that it is achievable.  Would you know how to test this scenario?

Comment: You should be able to add additional users to your demo account. If you are interested in building a partner integration, I would recommend going through https://www.docusign.com/partners/become-a-partner

Comment: Yes you can add multiple users, both admins and not admins to your demo account.  You can also create multiple demo accounts, with users, and add your app to the second account.  The above enables you to try out the different variations of your app working for your clients.

Comment: Ok, I've created a second account however don't know which call to make to add my app to the second account?

Comment: Figured out how to do this :)